# VS2015 Update 1 bug, or bad C++: Why can't a friend class access its friend's protected destructor?

Tags: c++, ice

The following appears to be a pattern employed by ZeroC ICE in the code it auto-generates, which appears to me to be a way they have made singletons (not sure why) for many releases of their tool now.  Various compilers have no problem with it, until I found today that Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (VS version 14.0.24720.00, VC++ version 19.00.23506) emits an error.  Before Update 1, VS2015 also had no problem with it.  I'm not sure whether it's a bug (regression?) in the VS2015 C++ compiler with Update 1, or bad (not standards-conformant) C++ code that other compilers let slide.

Here is an example of the code pattern:

```
class Foo {
protected:
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    friend class Foo_init;
};

class Foo_init {
public:
    Foo init;
};

static Foo_init staticFooInit;
```

VS2015 Update 1 emits these errors:

```
example.cpp(13): error C2248: 'Foo::~Foo': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Foo'
example.cpp(3): note: see declaration of 'Foo::~Foo'
example.cpp(1): note: see declaration of 'Foo'
```

I found one (as yet unanswered) [ZeroC ICE forum post](https://forums.zeroc.com/forum/bug-reports/46108-compile-3-6-1-demos-in-visual-studio-2015) which seems related to this, but otherwise I haven't found out in my Google searching anything that convinces me whether this is a compiler issue or bad code.  I admit I don't know ZeroC ICE very well, nor do I use C++ friend classes enough to have a deep understanding of what you can and can't do with them.  I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable can shed some light on it.

Comment: Obvious [compiler] bug is obvious.

Comment: In case this is indeed a compiler bug, I posted a bug report to Microsoft here:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2148128

Comment: Honestly, it still feels wrong to call a protected destructor on a friend even if it's legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on your exact problem, but it reminds me of a problem I had a while ago, where forward declared classes would have an unexpected scope.  this page [cppreference class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) highlights the rules, that a forward-declared class has the most local scope.  However, your example on my VS2015u3 does not fail either.

I think the fix is probably to forward declare the class which is a friend before the class, so that it has a well defined scope.

When you have a class such as

```
class Example {
     int someFunction( class SomeOtherClass & param );
};
```

The compiler treats declaration of `SomeOtherClass` which is within the local scope.

This means that

```
class Example {
     int someFunction( class SomeOtherClass & param );
};

class SomeOtherClass {
          ...
};
```

Declares three classes `Example`  `Example::SomeOtherClass` and `SomeOtherClass`

Changing your example to

```
class Foo_init;

class Foo {
  protected:
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    friend Foo_init;
 };

class Foo_init {
  public:
    Foo init;
 };

 static Foo_init staticFooInit;
```

Should work

Comment: I think you've got it!  I didn't consider the scoping before.

Answer (score -7):

You have used an identifier that starts with an underscore and then a capital letter. These names are reserved for the implementation, and using them in user code is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll edit my question to fix that.  I don't think it matters of my original question though.

Comment: Also, ZeroC ICE does the same. :)