# friend class cannot access protected member

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

This code used to work fine with Visual Studio 2015, but it not longer works with Visual Studio 2015 update 1.

```
class Foo
{
protected:

    virtual ~Foo() {};
    friend class Foo__init;
};

class Foo__init
{
public:

    Foo _init;
};

static Foo__init _Foo_init;
```

It fails with the following error:

```
Error   C2248   'Foo::~Foo': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Foo'
```

Is this a compiler bug or is the code ill formed?

Comment: Mayhbe you want to make the destructor of Foo public.

Comment: I'm not asking about that. :)

Comment: What happens if you put `class Foot__init;` before the definition of `Foo`?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376316/vs2015-update-1-bug-or-bad-c-why-cant-a-friend-class-access-its-friends-pr

Comment: Also, drop the `_Capital` and the `double__underscore`. Those names are reserved.

Comment: @T.C. if you write an answer on either one of these questions we can mark one of them as duplicate  ;)

Comment: @T.C. I thought double underscores were only reserved at the _start_ of names? Does this apply within names too?

Comment: @underscore_d That's for C, IIRC. They are reserved [everywhere](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3) in C++.

Comment: Great concise link, thanks! Very relevant: "Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace." - as most people seem to overlook this and only advise against `_CapitalAfterUnderscore` - which is sure to cause undiagnosable horror when their implementation starts using `_myName`

Comment: @underscore_d `_myName` is only reserved in the global namespace (so the implementation can't make it a macro, for instance), unlike `_Capital`.

Comment: @selbie it doesn't make any difference to add a Foo__init destructor

Comment: @Holt it's the same if I add `class Foo__init;` before the definition of `Foo`

Comment: @José - My bad. I removed my comment when I noticed that Foo__init doesn't actually inherit.

Comment: note that this is bad style, a destructor should either be virtual and public, or non-virtual and protected. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend):

> The friend declaration appears in a class body and grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears.

So it's a compiler bug. Both `g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010` and `Ubuntu clang version 3.6.2-1 (tags/RELEASE_362/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.2)` compiles this code ( I added `int main() {}` ).

Comment: It is a bug indeed, but this cannot be justified by stating that the other main vendors compile it while VC++ doesn't ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's a compiler bug. It works in VS2008

Comment: Pretty sure is a compiler bug, but destructor is required to destroy the Foo member, this should only work because the friend class.

Comment: Yes, In the current scenario we do not have any Foo object. it is strange why it is trying to access it.