# Difference in gcc and cl with friend class with same name in nested and global namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, friend, cl

I have a code where class A and B are defined in global namespace. Same thing is repeated in a nested namespace. However in nested namespace when it sees friend declaration of Class B in Class A, it considers it to be global class B with msvc cl compiler whereas with nested::B in gcc.

```
class A{
    friend class B;
    protected:
        int i; 
        A(){
            i=0;
           }
}; //end of class A

class B{
    A* create(){
        return new A();
        }
}; //end of class B

int main() { 
     B object;
     return 0;
}

namespace nested{
// This forward declaration fixed the error.
//class B;
class A{
    friend class B;
    protected:
        int i; 
        A(){
            i=0;
           }
}; //end of class A

class B{
    A* create(){
        return new A();
        }
}; //end of class B

int main() { 
     B object;
     return 0;
}
} //end of nested
```

It compiles fine with gcc-7.2 but gives below errors with Visual-Studio 17.

> [ on line - return new A;] error C2248: 'nested::A::A' cannot access protected member declared in class 'nested::A'
>
> [ on line - A() in nested namespace]note: see declaration of 'nested::A::A'
>
> [ on class A in nested namespace]note: see declaration of 'nested::A'

I found the above commented forward declaration fixes the error.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376316/vs2015-update-1-bug-or-bad-c-why-cant-a-friend-class-access-its-friends-pr)

My understanding is in nested namespace in class A, it is considering it to be friend with global class B, as it has not seen nested::B yet. But, when we declare a class as friend, shouldn't it first lookup in local namespace (over another pass of compiler or something).

My question is - is there a c++ standard defined and which is the buggy compiler here (if any). I would like it to work with Visual Studio without or with minimal code changes.

**Edit 1:**
I found some free version of C++ standard on github. Sorry, I got tex files only.
[Link](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/classes.tex)

```
\indextext{local class!friend}%
\indextext{friend!local class and}%
If a friend declaration appears in a local class\iref{class.local} and the
name specified is an unqualified name, a prior declaration is looked
up without considering scopes that are outside the innermost enclosing
non-class scope.
For a friend function declaration, if there is no
prior declaration, the program is ill-formed.
For a friend class
declaration, if there is no prior declaration, the class that is
specified belongs to the innermost enclosing non-class scope, but if it is
subsequently referenced, its name is not found by name lookup
until a matching declaration is provided in the innermost enclosing
non-class scope.
\begin{example}
\begin{codeblock}
class X;
void a();
void f() {
  class Y;
  extern void b();
  class A {
  friend class X;   // OK, but \tcode{X} is a local class, not \tcode{::X}
  friend class Y;   // OK
  friend class Z;   // OK, introduces local class \tcode{Z}
  friend void a();  // error, \tcode{::a} is not considered
  friend void b();  // OK
  friend void c();  // error
  };
  X* px;            // OK, but \tcode{::X} is found
  Z* pz;            // error: no \tcode{Z} is found
}
\end{codeblock}
\end{example}
```

I am trying to understand the language

> a prior declaration is looked up without considering scopes that are outside the innermost enclosing non-class scope.

This feels like msvc cl is doing right thing and my understanding is "look for last declaration" without worrying about scope.
But, in code example

```
friend class X;   // OK, but \tcode{X} is a local class, not \tcode{::X}
```

Doesn't this suggest it refers to a local class and not global class, but since there was no local definition of X, on name lookup it referred to global X. Since in my case, there is a local definition of friend class, that should be referred?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you do `friend class ::B`?

Comment: It still gives same error. Other way could be writing `friend class nested::B` in nested namespace which is like explicitly telling `nested::B` is friend of `nested::A`. But, I would like to both code in global and nested namespace to be same.